# Selenium test 'Unable to locate element' in IE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, automated-tests

I have created an automated test that logs a user in to a site and performs certain operations. The test first runs in Firefox, Chrome and then IE. It runs perfectly in Firefox, closes the browser and then performs the test in Chrome and again closes the browser. When the exact same test opens the URL in IE it says it is unable to locate the element 'UserName' for the login process.

I have a wait function which I tried to extend in case it was a problem with the page rendering but this didn't work. When using the dev tools and searching for the element it finds it no problem so I am confused as to how it fails in the test.

Does anyone know what could cause this in IE?

The HTML for the text field looks like this...

The Selenium code that works in FF and Chrome but not IE is:

private Results _Test_Login(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Results rt;

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("MyURL");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Click();
        TextboxOperation type = new TextboxOperation("UserName", driver, "Success", EnumSearchType.ById);
        OperationExecutor.PerformOperations(type);

        rt = new Results(driver.Url, driver.PageSource, "Existing Users");

        return rt;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Login()
    {
        List<IWebDriver> drivers = new List<IWebDriver>() { firefoxDriver, chromeDriver, ieDriver };
        foreach (IWebDriver driver in drivers)
        {
            Results results = _Test_Login(driver);

            if (results.Exception != null)
            {
                throw results.Exception;
            }

            Assert.IsFalse(results.ErrorState);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type of locator are you using for locating username ? Are you using xpath?

Comment: I have tried using both the id and xpath and both result in the same error. But it works perfectly in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using? 
try with latest selenium jar 2.26.0

Comment: I am using Selenium Webdriver for all browsers.

Comment: Show your html code for the page and also paste your code that is running fine in FF nut giving error in IE.

Comment: Please post more info...like HTML part of Username field and your  Automation code which tries to access the Username field...Since it's Difficult to find the root cause

Comment: Note: This is a test created for the one page only to separate it from all my other tests.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to put a pause just before trying to locate an element because the page or frame is not yet ready.   Or, if you don't want to have a pause, you can use a time-limited while loop wrapping a try-catch that handles error conditions and retries the find if it fails.)